# Filtrar busca para apenas ID's que tenham mais de um registro vinculado POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Na query abaixo consigo buscar o maior reduzido vinculado a conta, porém preciso que ele filtre apenas nos id's que possuem mais de um reduzido vinculado. A tabela possui mais de 4000 reduzidos

```
SELECT (id,
        MAX(reduzido))
FROM contas
INNER JOIN reduzidocontas ON contas.id = reduzidocontas.idconta
AND reduzidocontas.ano = 2020
GROUP BY contas.id;
```

exemplo:

```
id | ano  | reduzido
85 | 2020 | 4745
**85 | 2020 | 43737**
**87 | 2020 | 44215**
**88 | 2020 | 1321**
**89 | 2020 | 32158*
```

- 

Quero buscar apenas quando se tem mais de um reduzido vinculado ao ID, como no 85 e não retornar quando se tem só um reduzido como o 87, 88 e 89.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente

```
SELECT (id,
        MAX(reduzido))
FROM contas
INNER JOIN reduzidocontas ON contas.id = reduzidocontas.idconta
AND reduzidocontas.ano = 2020
GROUP BY contas.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT reduzido) > 1
```

Não se se postgresql aceita um having que não esteja no select , senão coloca.